# Perl syntactical details - list context with or without parens?

Tags: perl

This works:

```
my $r = someSubroutine( map { ( 0 => $_ ) } @hosts)
```

This does not work, giving a syntax error:

```
my $r = someSubroutine( map { 0 => $_ } @hosts)
```

What I think I understand is that the `{ }` after the map amounts to a closure or anonymous subroutine.

But if I put a "`value, value`" at the end of a normal subroutine, it will return a list of those values. If I use this brevity with the map, it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, this is a very strange statement. The list that `map` produces will look like

```
0, $hosts[0], 0, $hosts[1], 0, $hosts[2], ...
```

so it's useless for assignment to a hash as it would be the same as

```
my  %hash = (0 => $hosts[-1])
```

`map` will accept either a *BLOCK* (which is what you're using) or a simple *EXPRESSION* for its first parameter. The problem here is that `{ 0 => $_ }` looks very  like an anonymous hash with a single element, which is an *EXPRESSION*, and that is what the parser guesses it is. An *EXPRESSION* requires a comma after it, before the second parameter, but when perl gets to the closing brace in `map { 0 => $_ } @hosts` it doesn't find one so it has to throw a syntax error as it is too far to backtrack to the opening brace and assume a block instead

[The documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) puts it like this

> `{` starts both hash references and blocks, so `map { ...` could be either the start of map BLOCK LIST or map EXPR, LIST. Because Perl doesn't look ahead for the closing `}` it has to take a guess at which it's dealing with based on what it finds just after the `{`. Usually it gets it right, but if it doesn't it won't realize something is wrong until it gets to the `}` and encounters the missing (or unexpected) comma. The syntax error will be reported close to the `}`, but you'll need to change something near the `{` such as using a unary `+` or semicolon to give Perl some help

The solution is to disambiguate it as you discovered. Any of these will work

```
map +( 0 => $_ ), @hosts

map(( 0 => $_ ), @hosts)

map { +0 => $_ } @hosts

map { ( 0 => $_ ) } @hosts

map { ; 0 => $_ } @hosts
```

Comment: Borodin: toolic is correct: my map is the input to the subroutine, not a scalar.  Were it in a scalar context that would be true, but its not.  It really looks like this:

`
 184         my $r = $self->sql_statement(
 185             'INSERT INTO project_sites (project_id, hostname) VALUES '
 186                 . join( ', ', map {'(?, ?)'} @{ $self->{hosts} } ),
 187             map { ( 0 => $_ ) } @{ $self->{hosts} }
 188         );
`

Comment: @Skylos: Ah, I completely overlooked the `someSubroutine()`. And I read toolic's comment as *The op code ...* rather than *The OP's code*. I thought he'd been looking at the output from [B::Terse](http://metacpan.org/module/B::Terse) or something. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`map` has two syntax:

```
map BLOCK LIST   e.g. map { f() } g()
map EXPR, LIST   e.g. map f(), g()
```

When Perl encounters `map`, it needs to determine which syntax was used. Let's say the first token after `map` is `{`. That's the start of a BLOCK, right? Hold on! Expressions can start with `{` too!

```
my $hash_ref = { key => 'val' };
```

The grammar is ambiguous. Perl has to "guess" which syntax you are using. Perl looks ahead at the next token to help guess, but sometimes it guesses incorrectly nonetheless. This is one of those cases.

The following are the standard workarounds for this:

```
map {; ... } LIST    # Force Perl to recognize the curly as the start of a BLOCK
map +{ ... }, LIST   # Force Perl to recognize the curly as the start of a hash constructor
```

- `;` can't be part of a hash constructor, so the `{` can only start a BLOCK.
- `+` necessarily starts an EXPR (and not a BLOCK). It's an operator that does nothing but help in situations like this.

For example,

```
map {; +{ $row->{id} => $row->{val} } } @rows
```

Answer (score 1):

This is described in perldoc on `map`: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html

In short you should use little helper like parens or `+`-symbol so perl will be able to parse `{...}` construct correctly:

```
my $r = someSubroutine( map { + 0 => $_ } @hosts)
```